# how to get every first 10 results of a query in laravel (php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach

i'm trying to get every first 10 results from my database. for example:

first 10 result:

```
-andi - anita - andry - budi - caplay - dennis - dekky - elroy -emmy - fanny
```

next 10 result:

```
-gray - gina -hanny - hanna - heny -inna -john -johanna -kiky - koko
```

here my query:

```
 $child_name = DB::table('tm_child')
            ->orderBy('Child_Name','asc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

and then the looping:

```
 @foreach($child_name as $index => $childName)


    <li>
        <a href="detailRekap/{{$childName->Child_ID}}">
            {{ $childName->Child_Name }}
        </a>
    </li>

@endforeach
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the error/non-required behavior.

Comment: do you want to have several arrays, each of them contain 10 entrys?

Comment: hmm,  i think @michael, it should be in array

Comment: If your intention is to paginate the results, there is a simple way to do it in laravel: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination

Comment: Could one of the solutions solve your problem or do you need further help with it?

Comment: to be honest i never use paginate concept, but i will try :D

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have an array like this:

```
array (
    array 10 (
       -andi - anita - andry - budi - caplay - dennis - dekky - elroy -emmy - fanny)
    array 10 (
       -gray - gina -hanny - hanna - heny -inna -john -johanna -kiky - koko)
```

You could change your query to include [chunk()](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_chunk)

```
 $child_name = DB::table('tm_child')
            ->orderBy('Child_Name','asc')
            ->get()->chunk(10);
```

But if you just want to get paginated results, you can simply use laravels [pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination):

```
$child_name = DB::table('tm_child')
                ->orderBy('Child_Name','asc')
                ->paginate(10);
```